# How to use Twitter API to check if a user/password is valid?

Tags: python, twitter

I have a user and a password and I'd like to use Twitter API (I'm using python-twitter) to check if those are valid data.

Comment: You might want to look into using OAuth instead. I personally *hate* sites/systems which requirement to provide login information from other sites; it's just not a good security practice.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not completely able to understand your question. Are you asking for a way to check whether you can log in to twitter with a given username/password combination?

Comment: yes, Nikwin. Right that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you grab the 0.7 version of [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/source/browse/twitter.py), a VerifyCredentials method has been added.  If the returned value is `None` then the username/password combo was incorrect.

I liked using `api.GetUser(username)` first to check if they provided a valid username and then using `api.VerifyCredentials()` to check the password -- this way I could informed the user which part of their login was incorrect.

As others have mentioned, Twitter is pushing for OAuth logins only and are expected to deprecate the existing username/passwd login method.

Answer (score 1):

urllib2 will raise HTTPError if the credentials are wrong, and the message will be 'HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized'. You could use a temporary instance of the API to make an authorized request (GetFriends(), for example) in a try/except block to determine if the credentials are valid.

```
import twitter, urllib2
checkCreds = twitter.Api(username, pass)
try:
  checkCreds.GetFriends()
except urllib2.HTTPError, status:
  if status.find('401') != -1:
    print 'Invalid username/password'
```

Twitter will [intentionally allow requests with missing or incorrect credentials](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Authentication) for publicly-accessible areas such as GetPublicTimeline() or GetUserTimeline().